# Launching windows C# application after installing it

Tags: c#

I have C# windows cs project. The application enables opening word documents and pictures as well and storing them in MS Access database. I made a setup and it installs well on computers where Visual Studio 2008 is installed, but when I install it on a computer with no VS installed, it installs and after that it doesn't starts to run. 
I can not run it.

Some other C# projects I made can be installed and run without problems on the same computers on which this application doesn't start.

Can anybody help me please what could be my problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps you built it using a version of the .NET Framework that isn't installed on the target machine?

Comment: You should provide some additional details. What does `doesn't starts to run` mean? Does it show error messages or just doesn't respond? Can you see the process in task manager?

Answer (score 0):

Possible lacks some of the .net framework components on computer with no Vs installed,because when you installing VS,all the necessary components are also installed

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it seems that the computer with no VS installed does not have `.NET framework` installed.

And where you are testing on computers with VS installed it obviously works as `.NET framework`is already installed.

I think there is an option in setup where you can specify `Prerequisites` before installing your application, google out more info on this.

This [link](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15helplib/MSIPrereq.htm) might help.

Answer (score 0):

If other Applications do run then it's possible that you may miss some dependencies.
Check if all dll's are installed properly. Which framework do you use ? Are the other C# projects also programmed in that framework ?